# c# - Calculations - RNG Game

Tags: c#

I am making a football game. In order to get a touchdown, you have to gain 100 yards. I have `public static int yardsLeft = 100;`. It goes through a loop, gaining so many yards each pass through. Once the `yardsLeft = 0`, it will exit. I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to get the yards gained at the end (touchdown), to be EXACTLY 100 yards.

I have this:

```
if (Program.yardsLeft >= 80)
{
    if (Program.chance >= 1 && Program.chance <= 5)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(80, (100 + 1));

    else if (Program.chance >= 6 && Program.chance <= 12)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(60, (79 + 1));

    else if (Program.chance >= 13 && Program.chance <= 24)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(20, (59 + 1));

    else if (Program.chance >= 25 && Program.chance <= 100)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(1, (19 + 1));
}
else if (Program.yardsLeft <= 79 && Program.yardsLeft >= 60)
{
    if (Program.chance >= 1 && Program.chance <= 10)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(60, 80);

    else if (Program.chance >= 11 && Program.chance <= 30)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(20, 60);

    else if (Program.chance >= 31 && Program.chance <= 100)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(1, 20);
}
else if (Program.yardsLeft <= 59 && Program.yardsLeft >= 40)
{
    if (Program.chance >= 1 && Program.chance <= 10)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(40, 60);

    else if (Program.chance >= 11 && Program.chance <= 30)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(20, 40);

    else if (Program.chance >= 31 && Program.chance <= 100)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(1, 20);
}
else if (Program.yardsLeft <= 39 && Program.yardsLeft >= 20)
{
    if (Program.chance >= 1 && Program.chance <= 10)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(30, 40);

    else if (Program.chance >= 11 && Program.chance <= 30)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(10, 30);

    else if (Program.chance >= 31 && Program.chance <= 100)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(1, 10);
}
else if (Program.yardsLeft <= 19)
{
    if (Program.chance >= 1 && Program.chance <= 10)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(15, 20);

    if (Program.chance >= 11 && Program.chance <= 30)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(10, 15);

    if (Program.chance >= 31 && Program.chance <= 100)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(1, 10);
}
```

First it checks if the yardsLeft is over 80, if it is, it has the chance to gain so many yards (up to 100)BUT, if the first time through, it doesn't gain more than 20 yards (to continue to the next check`else if (Program.yardsLeft <= 79 && Program.yardsLeft >= 60)` it's going to go right back to the `else if (Program.yardsLeft <= 79 && Program.yardsLeft >= 60)` and once again add something that leads up to 100, MEANING AT THE END, the result will pass 100.

EXAMPLE

```
if (yardsLeft is 80 or more)
    {
        // generate number somewhere through 60-80 (not ever exceed 100)
        // generate number somehwere between 20-60 (not ever exceeding 100
        // generator number somewehere between 1-20 (not ever exceeding 100)
    }
    else if (yardsLeft is between 60-20)
    {
        // generate number somewhere through 40-60 (not ever exceed 100)
        // generate number somehwere between 20-40 (not ever exceeding 100
        // generator number somewehere between 1-20 (not ever exceeding 100)
    }
```

THE FINAL RESULT `CAN NOT` EXCEED 100. This is what I'm trying to say. Each time it loops, i want it generate some number that at the end, will never exceed 100.

Comment: that is ALOT of if/else if's

Comment: Reduce this question to something that can be understood.

Comment: Can't you just check two clauses at the beginning like so: `if (Program.yardsLeft >= 80 && Program.yardsLeft < 100 )`

Comment: Within the first check, it checks if its over 80, if it is, it adds up but doesnt pass 100. say i get 10 yards, its gonna loop, then go right back to that statement cause its still above 80, and its going to exceed the final result over 100

Comment: have you thought about implementing Math.Min and checking the result vs 100 and returning the minimum of the two? That way, you'll never return a number greater than 100.

Comment: I updated it, hopefully it's more understandable. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Can't you replace all those if/else with a switch?

Comment: Yeah, but my main priority is keeping the gained yards at the end of the loop to 100. I'm not sure how to do that. I gain so many yards each loop, but if it's under 20 the 1st time, its going to go through the if statement >= 80 that making it at the end over 100.

Comment: Could you maybe give an example of the problem rather than trying to describe it abstractly? Abstract definitions will theoretically get you the most correct answer, but examples are more answerable.

Comment: I added an example at the bottom of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to just place this block after the rest of your code:

```
Program.gained = Math.Min(Program.gained, Program.yardsLeft);
```

This means that if the yards gained is greater than the number of yards needed to get to 0, it will be set to the number of yards left. So when you later (presumably) decrement `Program.yardsLeft` by `Program.gained`, it won't go below 0.

---

The basics: `Math.Min` returns the minimum of the parameters you give it. This statement sets `Program.gained` to a new value based on the value given during the earlier code. This "clamps" the value of `Program.gained` to be below `yardsLeft`. Here's a simpler usage:

```
int yardsYouCanRun = 112;
int yardsYouTraveled = Math.Min(yardsYouCanRun, 100);
// yardsYouTraveled is Math.Min(112, 100), which is 100.

int yardsICanRun = 15;
int yardsITraveled = Math.Min(yardsICanRun, 100);
// yardsITraveled is Math.Min(15, 100), which is 15.
```

This represents the situation where you're tracking the number of yards you can run from zero, but want to limit it to 100 because that's the maximum distance you can possibly run. The minimum of the two is the distance ran. As you can see, you can run the entire length, but I can only run 15 yards, so you get an 100-yard touchdown but I only end up at the 15 yard line. This is "clamping" the value of `yardsXCanRun` below 100 yards.

This is the same as in the earlier line of code, but instead of having 100 yards that you or I can run, you only have `Program.yardsLeft` to run.

Comment: Thank you. This does work, however can you explain how this works? I'm trying to learn as much as I can, and I'm really dedicated to learning.

Comment: @Donavon Edited to expand, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are wanting is this:

```
    if (Program.yardsLeft >= 80)
    {
        if (Program.chance >= 1 && Program.chance <= 5)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(80, (100 + 1));

        else if (Program.chance >= 6 && Program.chance <= 12)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(60, (79 + 1));

        else if (Program.chance >= 13 && Program.chance <= 24)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(20, (59 + 1));

        else if (Program.chance >= 25 && Program.chance <= 100)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(1, (19 + 1));
    }
    else if (Program.yardsLeft <= 79 && Program.yardsLeft >= 60)
    {
        if (Program.chance >= 1 && Program.chance <= 10)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(60, 80);

        else if (Program.chance >= 11 && Program.chance <= 30)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(20, 60);

        else if (Program.chance >= 31 && Program.chance <= 100)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(1, 20);
    }
    else if (Program.yardsLeft <= 59 && Program.yardsLeft >= 40)
    {
        if (Program.chance >= 1 && Program.chance <= 10)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(40, 60);

        else if (Program.chance >= 11 && Program.chance <= 30)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(20, 40);

        else if (Program.chance >= 31 && Program.chance <= 100)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(1, 20);
    }
    else if (Program.yardsLeft <= 39 && Program.yardsLeft >= 20)
    {
        if (Program.chance >= 1 && Program.chance <= 10)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(30, 40);

        else if (Program.chance >= 11 && Program.chance <= 30)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(10, 30);

        else if (Program.chance >= 31 && Program.chance <= 100)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(1, 10);
    }
    else if (Program.yardsLeft <= 19 && Program.yardsLeft !>= 100)
    {
        if (Program.chance >= 1 && Program.chance <= 10)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(15, 20);

    if (Program.chance >= 11 && Program.chance <= 30)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(10, 15);

    if (Program.chance >= 31 && Program.chance <= 100)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(1, 10);
    }
    else
   {return;}//return the value if over 100
```

Simply you didn't put an argument to check if the yards left was over 100 in the final elseif

Another way do doing what you are here is making the random dynamic by using .yardsLeft would always only allow you to get to 100 and never anything more.

```
if (Program.chance >= 31 && Program.chance <= 100)
        Program.gained = Program.r.Next(1, program.yardsLeft);
```