# C# - Loop ending result

Tags: c#

I'm going to try to explain this with the best of my ability, so please bear with me. I'm making a game, and basically there's 100 yards. you start at 100, and its on a loop, generating numbers and subtracting them from the 100 yards. Once the number hits 0, the loop will stop.

Take a look at this code:

```
int yardsLeft = 100;
    // this is on a loop until 'yardsLeft = 0'
if (yardsLeft >= 80)
{
    // 10% chance of generating a number 80-100
    // 20% chance of generating a number 40-80
    // 70% chance of generating a number 1-40

    // Say it hits the 10% chance and generates the number 85 - there's 15 yards left
    // it will pass through the if statements entering the `if (yardsLeft < 40)` - say that hits 20 once more. at the end once the yardsLeft finally equals 0, the yards added up each loop will be over 100. in this case 120
    -------------------------------
    // but if the generated number generates a 70% chance and hits a number 1-20, it's going to stay in the `yardsLeft > 80` if statment-
    // therefore having the potential to exceed the number '100' once the `yardsLeft = 0`
}
else if (yardsLeft >= 40 && yardsLeft <= 79) { } // this would activate if the 20% chance got generated
if (yardsLeft < 40)
    {
    // 10% chance of generating a number 30-39
    // 20% chance of generating a number 10-29
    // 70% chance of generating a number 1-9
    }
```

My problem:

> if the generated number generates a 70% chance and hits a number 1-20, it's going to stay in the `yardsLeft > 80` if statment,
>   therefore having the potential to exceed the number '100' once the `yardsLeft = 0`

So how if it did enter the `yardsLeft >= 80`, how can I make sure it generates a number that which at the end, it generated exactly `100` yards (numbers added up)

Here is my loop:

```
while (yardsLeft > 0)
{
    int[] playResult = new int[i + 1];
    playResult[i] = r.Next(1, 4);

    switch (playResult[i])
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine(BuffaloBills.QB + " hands it off to " + BuffaloBills.RB + " for a gain of " + Calculations.Play() + " yards. \n");
            yardsLeft -= gained;
            i++;
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine(BuffaloBills.QB + " passes it " + BuffaloBills.WR + " for a gain of " + Calculations.Play() + " yards. \n");
            yardsLeft -= gained;
            i++;
            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine(BuffaloBills.QB + " doesn't find anyone open so he rushes for a gain of " + Calculations.Play() + " yards. \n");
            yardsLeft -= gained;
            i++;
            break;
    }
}
```

Here's my variables

```
public static Random r = new Random();
public static int gained;
public static int yardsLeft = 100;
public static int i = 0;
public static int chance = r.Next(1, 101);
```

Comment: I don't think you're understanding. Every loop passed, there's going to be a generated number. Those numbers add up until it reaches 100, also making `yardsLeft = 0`. my method of doing this makes the final result exceed `100`

Comment: Because when it loops, and hits the `yardsLeft >= 80', that's not calculated right, so its going to add over 100. i need it to be 100 exact. but im not sure how

Comment: How is this different form your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333268/c-sharp-calculations-rng-game)?  Why not just clarify the question there?

Comment: why can the final result not exceed 100? if you get to 99 yards, and the next random number is 100, just return `(100-99) = 1`.

Comment: This is an American Football text simulator. In a football field, there are 100 yards.

Comment: You're missing my point - it doesn't matter what the final random number generated is because you will have exceeded 100. Therefore you only have to return the distance travelled between the previous run, and 100.

Comment: @MrLister - i only read this comment    // this is on a loop until 'yardsLeft = 0'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just returning the number from your top if/else if/else statements, wait until the end of the block and return there. That will allow you to gather all of the logic to make the calculation in one spot.

```
private int Play(int yardsLeft) // Pass in the total yards left here
{
    var yards = 0;

    if (yardsLeft >= 80)
    {
        yards = // The result of your 10/20/70% calculation
    }
    else if (yardsLeft >= 40) { } // Same deal
    else { } // Again, same as in the if

    return yards > yardsLeft ? yardsLeft : yards;
}
```

You could also rework this to provide a string that would say whether or not a Touchdown was scored. (Have the `yardsLeft` parameter be a `ref` so that you can adjust the remaining yards inside this method.)